# jQuery thumbnail scroller overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use [jQuery thumbnail scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-thumbnail-scroller) , but as soon as the width of the images surpasses the container width, instead of scrolling, the overflow sits underneath the scroller. Given that I have just started to learn JavaScript, I have been tweaking it a little bit, but no luck so far. The address of the website is http://stolenrecord.com/reviews.php?page=1.

Any clues?

Comment: Your thumbnailScroller.js script is not being loaded on the page provided. Change your jquery.thumbnailScroller.js to js/jquery.thumbnailScroller.js like the other ones

Comment: @Furry the code is pretty much the same as the given original. You can find it here: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-thumbnail-scroller

Comment: @GrayB Yes it is. I just checked!

Comment: I'm loading your page from the link provided, and you have javascript errors, one of them is the missing jquery.thumbnailScroller.js script.

Comment: @GrayB, you are right! I forgot to add the js directory. Thank you very much for pointing this out. I dont think I can choose your comment as the answer on stackoverflow. I would otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thumbnailScroller.js script is not being loaded on the page provided.

Change your `jquery.thumbnailScroller.js` to `js/jquery.thumbnailScroller.js` like the other ones